# How can I smoothen edges in a superimposed image?

Tags: paint.net

How can I make this image look smooth using Paint.Net?

[image]

What tools should I use?

Comment: I don't know anything about Paint.NET as I don't use it. Sorry. However, if it has a clone tool, you could use that, set to a soft edged brush, and clone over the lines. If not, then GIMP has one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to have repeating identical horizontal stripes. You can select with the rectangle selection tool one stripe and copy it to a new layer. Flip it vertically and duplicate the flipped version. Move them so that every seam has mirrored versions in the both sides of the seam. The result:

[image]

In Paint.NET you must paste as new layer. Pasting happens by default to the original layer. It's different in GIMP and Photoshop.

BTW. No idea how useful this would look if I could see the whole image.